# how to send the selected drop down element from client to server using node js - express

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js and i am stuck to send the selected drop down element (like java,angular see below ex ) from client to server using node js - express. When i try to print it in console. system displays an error message "undefined " for drop down elements. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

EJS code

```
<form method="POST" action="/viewreg.html">
<select name="Courses" form="Courses">
<option value="Java">Java</option>
<option value="Angular">Angular</option>
<option value="Automation">Automation</option>
</select>
<input type='submit'name ='register' onclick="form.action='viewreg.html'"
</form>`
```

Server side -

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const path=require('path');
const hostname = 'x.x.x.x'
const port = 80;
const app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
const dir=path.join(__dirname,'public');
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));

app.post('/viewreg.html',function(req,res) {
const newuser= {
        emp_name:req.body.emp_name, 
        emp_id:req.body.emp_id, 
        phone_no:req.body.phone_no, 
        Team:req.body.selectpicker,
        courses:req.body.Courses,
    }
console.log(newuser);
});
```

Comment: Why you define `onclick="form.action='viewreg.html'"` for the submit button? It does not make any sense. The action URL is already defined in the form

Comment: Also, when `POST /viewreg.html` request is sent, have you checked the DevTool of the browser? Is the POST request sent? Is the selected element value sent through the HTTP request? Node.js is the technology to receive the request. For "how to send...", you need to check browser side code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to revisit the below issues which exist in your code.

- Change your action url from `action="/viewreg.html">` to
  `action="/viewreg">`
- There is no need to have `onclick="form.action='viewreg.html'"` in
  your `submit` button.
- You don't have an `ID` attribute attached to your `<select>` tag
  where as you have a `form` attribute incorrectly over there.

You need to re-write your `ejs` tempalte as,

```
<form method="POST" action="/viewreg">
    <select name="Courses" id="Courses">
        <option value="Java">Java</option>
        <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
        <option value="Automation">Automation</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit'name ='register'>
</form>
```

Also try changing your `console.log(newuser);` as,

```
console.log(req.body.Courses);
```

which will resolve your issue.

Hope this helps!